# Check if the connection and transfer was successful with AutoIT and WinSCP

Tags: autoit, winscp

I use AutoIT an WinSCP to connect to a sftp Server and transfer data. This works great. But now i want to check if the connection and transfer was successful or if winscp showed an error.
This is how i connect and transfer.

The best would be, that after this line of code, i can use a variabel like $error and ask if there is something in it or not

```py
Run('WinSCP.com /command "open sftp://user:password@server.de/" "put c:\\_data\*" "exit"')
```

Comment: [`RunWait()`](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/RunWait.htm) returns process' exit code.

Comment: perfect, thank you :)